# Steps to install PHP 5.4.3 from rpm and yum?

Tags: php, yum, rpm

I got a link saying following steps of installation of PHP 5.4.3.

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

yum install php54w
```

Can i use above method safely?

Or any other rpm that i can use?

Comment: What happens when you run `yum install php`?  I think the default Red Hat repository *should* have PHP...

Comment: yum installs PHP 5.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that method if you trust their site.

That rpm command sets up a yum repository pointing to their site and the yum command installs it.

You may need to run `yum clean all` and `yum update` after adding the repository.

You could also install from source code from http://php.net.